# find Control in TemplateField of GridView with jquery or javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

On client side  button click event, I want to get control id that are place in Item template of Grid View. I tried this code but it doesn't work. Thanks

```
function buttonClicked(sender, args) {
    var gv = $find('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

    var textbox = $GridView1.findControl(gv.get_element().parentNode, "Textbox");
}
```

Here is the Gridview

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   <div>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="KurzDS" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox" runat="server" Text="Textbox"></asp:TextBox>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Text="Textbox1"></asp:TextBox>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btn" Text='btn' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>'  CommandName="btn" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you can give us an excerpt of what the generated html would look like, I can help you with the JavaScript required to find the element you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for including the GridView example. Now that I can see what you are attempting, I have a much better answer for you.

First, make a slight change to the button template, change out `CommandArgument` for `OnClientClick`and since you are using this button client side instead of posting back to the server, you can simplify it like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" Text='btn' OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ID", "YourJavascriptFunction({0} - 1); return false;") %>' runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
```

I have the click event call your JavaScript function and it sends in a parameter of the server side resolved id. Notice I subtract 1 first though. This is because the server side ASP.Net Eval function give the ID starting at 1. But, each of the ids that get generated for your text input elements start with a zero base.

Now look at the JavaScript function below.

```
// Clicking the first button sends in a 0, second sends in a 1, etc.
function YourJavascriptFunction(id) {
  // each of the TextBox1 elements has an ASP.Net server side
  // generated id that ends with GridView2_Textbox1_0,
  // GridView2_Textbox1_1, etc.
  let selectId = "input[id$='GridView2_Textbox1_" + id + "']";

  // The text we use in the querySelector function states
  // find the DOM element with a tag of "input" where the id
  // ends with . . . The $ in id$= is the part that says the
  // value must "end with"
  let textBox1 = document.querySelector(selectId);

  // Now that we have TextBox1 from the same row as the button, 
  // getting the value is easy.
  alert(textBox1.value);
}
```

I left off a jQuery example as this querySelector command works in almost every browser including IE8 and above, so you shouldn't need jQuery for something this simple.

Let me know if I can help further.